# Counting Words from one columns of Dataframe to Another Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having dataframe `idf` as below.

```
       feature_name idf_weights
2488    kralendijk  11.221923
3059    night       0
1383    ebebf       0
```

I have another Dataframe `df`

```
     message                   Number of Words in each message  
0   night kralendijk ebebf          3
```

I want to add `idf weights` from `idf` for each word in the "df" dataframe in a new column.

The output will look like the below:

```
    message                   Number of Words in each message   Number of words with idf_score>0
0   night kralendijk ebebf                 3                     1
```

Here is what I've tried so far, but it's giving the total count of words instead of word having `idf_weight>0`:

```
words_weights = dict(idf[['feature_name', 'idf_weights']].values)
df['> zero'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: count([words_weights.get(word, 11.221923) for word in x.split()]))
```

Output

```
     message                   Number of Words in each message   Number of words with idf_score>0
0   night kralendijk ebebf                 3                     3
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a list comprehension:

```
# set up a dictionary for easy feature->weight indexing
d = idf.set_index('feature_name')['idf_weights'].to_dict()
# {'kralendijk': 11.221923, 'night': 0.0, 'ebebf': 0.0}

df['> zero'] = [sum(d.get(w, 0)>0 for w in x.split()) for x in df['message']]

## OR, slighlty faster alternative
# df['> zero'] = [sum(1 for w in x.split() if d.get(w, 0)>0) for x in df['message']]
```

output:

```
                  message  Number of Words in each message  > zero
0  night kralendijk ebebf                                3       1
```

Comment: You can clearly drop all records with a weight equals to 0. `idf[idf['idf_weights'] > 0].set_index(...)...`

Comment: @Corralien yes, I have thought of it, but it shouldn't impact performance (except to create the dictionary if really there are so many 0s)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.findall`: the goal here is to create a list of feature names with a weight greater than 0 to find in each message.

```
pattern = fr"({'|'.join(idf.loc[idf['idf_weights'] > 0, 'feature_name'])})"
df['Number of words with idf_score>0'] = df['message'].str.findall(pattern).str.len()
print(df)

# Output
                  message  Number of Words in each message  Number of words with idf_score>0
0  night kralendijk ebebf                                3                                 1
```